# Coger el siguiente número double de una cadena

Tags: java

Muestro como ejemplo el siguiente archivo, que leo para extraer su contenido. Eso lo hago bien y me quedo solo con los números, el primero es un entero que indica la cantidad de números *doubles* que hay.

```
Álava 2 10.5 20.3
Alicante 3 0 30.2 -12.7 
Albacete 0
Almería 1 122.17
```

Creo una nueva cadena para esos números, tanto entero como *doubles*, separando con un `\n` para saber lo que pertenece a cada línea. De ahi tengo que calcular la media de los *doubles*. La salida sería, también *double*.

```
Álava  15.4
Alicante  5.833333333333333
Albacete  0.0
Almería  122.17
```

Código:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Ficherociudad {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cad=" ";
        try {
            Scanner archivo = new Scanner(
                    new File("C:archivo_salida.txt"));
            while(archivo.hasNextLine()==true){
            cad = cad+ archivo.nextLine();
            cad = cad + "\n";
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No pude abrir el fichero");
        }
        System.out.println(cad);
        String cadnueva="";
        for (int i = 0; i <= cad.length() - 1; i++) {
            char c=cad.charAt(i);
            if((int)c<=96 || (int)c>=123){
                cadnueva=cadnueva+c;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(cadnueva);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,
He cambiado un par de cosas de tú código que creo que son necesarias. A continuación de propongo una idea, quizás no la mejor porque yo hubiera usado otros medios, pero al menos cumple con tu propósito si el fichero que lee siempre tiene la estructura correcta.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cad="";
        try {
            Scanner archivo = new Scanner(
                    new File("fichero.txt"));
            while(archivo.hasNextLine()==true){
                cad = cad+ archivo.nextLine();
                // Solo añade el salto de línea si tiene más lineas
                if(archivo.hasNextLine())
                    cad = cad + "\n";
            }
            // Hay que cerrar los flujos cuando ya no se necesitan más
            archivo.close();

            System.out.println(cad);
            // Se obtiene un array de String con las líneas que se leen del fichero
            String lista[] = cad.split("\n");
            String cadenaFinal = "";
            // Iteramos sobre cada linea de forma separada
            for(String actual : lista) {
                // Dividimos la linea en partes para trabajar
                String valores[] = actual.split(" ");
                // El segundo elemento es la cantidad de doubles
                int elementos = Integer.parseInt(valores[1]);
                // Suma total
                double total = 0;
                // iteramos la cantidad de elementos que se hayan especificado
                for(int x = 0; x < elementos; x++) {
                    total += Double.parseDouble(valores[x+2]);
                }
                // Si no hay elementos no se hace media, (0/0 lanza error aritmético)
                if(elementos > 0) {
                    total /= elementos;
                }
                cadenaFinal = cadenaFinal + valores[0] + " " + total + "\n";
            }

            System.out.println(cadenaFinal);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No pude abrir el fichero");
        }  

    }
```

Lo primero que he cambiado ha sido incluir toda la lógica en el try/catch, porque si no encuentra el fichero no debería hacer nada.

He cambiado la inicialización de `cad` a vacío para que no afecte a los `split`.
Sólo añade salto de línea si hay más elementos para que al hacer ´split` no añada al array una nueva línea vacía.

Lo demás creo que está suficientemente explicado en los comentarios, aunque si tuvieras dudas puedes preguntar.

La salida que me ha dado es la siguiente:

```
Álava 15.4
Alicante 5.833333333333333
Albacete 0.0
Almería 122.17
```

Espero que fuera lo que necesitabas.